# How to retrieve data from curl -d command with Python using BaseHTPPRequestHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, curl

First of all I should mention that ı am beginner on rest API and python,it is my first try.
I want to use just standart lib.

ı try to use this curl terminal command on my python server.

```
curl -d "id=23&answer=Rad Mobile" -X POST http://localhost:8000/answer
```

My server code is like this.
To get url coming post  request.
Functions in class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

```
def do_POST(self):
        url = urlparse(self.path)
        if url.path == "/answer":
            return self.answer_q(parse_qs(url.query))
        self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Not Found \n')
```

to understand answer

```
def answer_q(self, query):

        global correct_a,index
        isCorrect = False

        if  "answer" in query:
            if query["answer"] == str.encode(json.dumps(data["results"][index]["correct_answer"])) :
                isCorrect = True
                correct_a += 1
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(query).encode())
       #self.wfile.write(json.dumps(data["results"][index]["correct_answer"]).encode())
87 line self.wfile.write(json.dumps(self.update_js(query['id'],isCorrect),indent = 2).encode())
        index=index+1
```

but ı get the error

File "serv.py", line 87, in answer_q
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(self.update_js(query['id'],isCorrect),indent = 2).encode())
KeyError: 'id'

```
but with this form it works.
```

curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/answer?id=23&answer=Rad_Mobile"

So ı guess that ı cannot read the string at the beginning of the curl with this curl -d " " -X POST command .How can ı catch id and answer.
Thanks a lot.